# Optimize a dictionary key conditional

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to optimize this piece of code. I'm sure there is a way to write it in a single line:

```
if 'value' in dictionary:
   x = paas_server['support']
else:
   x = []
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `if 'support' in dictionary:` ?

Comment: `x=pass_server['support'] if 'value' in dicitonary else []`

Comment: @sahasrara62 Exactly what the OP asked for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use dictionary `get()` method as:

`x = dictionary.get('support', [])`

if `support` is not a key in the dictionary, it returns second method's argument, here, an empty list.